# Add axis label to plot in matplotlib, by passing them as arguments to plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to set the `x-label` and `y-label` in a **matplotlib-plot** passing them as an parameter to the `plot()` function.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
def plot_something(data, plot_conf):
    data.plot(**plot_conf)
    ...do some other stuff...

plot_conf = {'title': 'Blabla', 'xlabel':'Time (s)', 'ylabel': 'Speed (m/s)'}
plot_something(data,plot_conf)
```

I would prefer not to use any additional function calls, like `xlabel()`

Comment: See the documentation of the [`pyplot.plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for valid kwargs. You can't pass xlabel, ylabel and title as arguments to the `plot()` method, as those are properties of `Axes` instances. The `plot()` method returns a `Line2D` instance. IMO the easiest and most intuitive way to achieve this would be to change your `plot_something()` function to actually use additional function calls.

Comment: A **simplified** explanation as to why you can not do this readily: You can have _several_ calls to the `plot()` method for _each_ `Axes` object (e.g. plot two or more different lines in same subplot). If each of these method calls were to set the title, xlabel and ylabel of the `Axes`, everything would get pretty messy pretty fast! Also, this wouldn't be as intuitive and object-oriented as it currently is.

Comment: @sjosund just to remind [you can upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400)  the answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @nordev already explained, you cannot pass through `plot()` the axis label, but inside your function you can get the active figure and then set the axis labels like the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_something(x, y, **kwargs):
    title  = kwargs.pop( 'title'  )
    xlabel = kwargs.pop( 'xlabel' )
    ylabel = kwargs.pop( 'ylabel' )
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    fig = plt.gcf()
    for axis in fig.axes:
        axis.set_title( title )
        axis.xaxis.set_label_text( xlabel )
        axis.yaxis.set_label_text( ylabel )
    return axis


plot_conf = {'title': 'Blabla', 'xlabel':'Time (s)', 'ylabel': 'Speed (m/s)'}
x = [1.,2.,3.]
y = [1.,4.,9.]
axis = plot_something(x=x,y=y, **plot_conf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The axis labels part didn't work for me in first go. I made it work by changing `set_label` to `set_label_text`

Comment: @Atlas7 thanks for the comment, I updated the answer